# How to annotate a QuerySet with a filtered self join in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

#### Motivation

I have a dataset with the results of sports matches, which I want to annotate with past performance in the time period leading up to each match.

The way I think about doing this is:

1. Annotate each `Match` with the set of matches which took place within the relevant time period (`MatchManager.matchset_within_period` below).
2. Annotate each `Match` with the aggregation of stats across this set of related matches (`MatchManager.annotate_with_stats` below).

I am able to do this with a somewhat convoluted query (outlined below) involving an extra `Dataset` model which I traverse up to and back down from in order to get a reference to the full set of matches, which I can then filter and aggregate.

#### Question

This approach seems really complicated, and probably bad for performance.  It's definitely difficult to follow (or at least unintuitive) for a reader.

Is there a way to obtain the match set I need for step (1) directly, without the extra model (e.g., using a Subquery direclty on `Match`)?

---

#### Example usage

**`In [1]`**

```
test_matches = Match.objects.filter(...)

Match.objects \
    .annotate_with_stats(for_days=300) \
    .filter(id__in=test_matches) \
    .values('pk', 'home_team_avg_score')
```

**`Out[1]`**

```
<MatchQuerySet [{'id': 287, 'home_team_avg_score': 91.04166666666667}, {'id': 288, 'home_team_avg_score': 91.21739130434783}, {'id': 289, 'home_team_avg_score': 92.45833333333333}]>
```

#### Simplified code

**`models.py (simplified)`**

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


# This model has no semantic meaning - it's purely for the query
class Dataset(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Season(models.Model):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(
        Dataset, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='seasons',
    )
    # ...


class Round(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(
        Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rounds',
    )
    # ...


class Match(models.Model):
    round = models.ForeignKey(
        Round, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='matches',
    )
    home_team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='home_matches',
    )
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    # ...
    objects = MatchManager()


class TeamMatchStats(models.Model):
    match = models.ForeignKey(
        Match, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='team_stats',
    )
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='match_stats',
    )
    score = models.IntegerField()
    # ...
```

**`managers.py (simplified)`**

```
def fm(x):
    '''
    Helper function for obtaining a self-referential matches set.
    '''
    if x.startswith('round'):
        raise ValueError('Cannot re-traverse upwards')
    return f'round__season__dataset__seasons__rounds__matches__{x}'


class MatchQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def matchset_within_period(self, td):
        # filter(date__lt): before this match
        # annotate/filter(time_before__lte): within x period
        return self \
                .filter(**{fm('date__lt'): F('date')}) \
                .annotate(
                        time_before=ExpressionWrapper(
                                F('date') - F(fm('date')),
                                output_field=DurationField(),
                        )
                ) \
                .filter(time_before__lte=td) \
                .values('pk')

    def annotate_with_stats(self, for_days):
        q_home_team = Q(**{fm('team_stats__team'): F('home_team')})
        team_avg_params = {
            'home_team_avg_score': Avg(
                fm('team_stats__score'), filter=q_home_team,
            )
        }  # In reality this is a dict comp getting a number of stats

        return self \
                .matchset_within_period(timedelta(days=for_days)) \
                .annotate(**team_avg_params)


MatchManager = MatchQuerySet.as_manager
```

Comment: That is indeed convoluted.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but why go through the whole `round__season__dataset__...` path instead of just filtering `home_team__match_stats__match` for date and then aggregating?

Comment: Hmm.  You're probably right that that's quicker.  I had been trying to avoid separate queries for home and away teams, but the approach via `match_stats` does seem to make more sense.